# How can I ensure that python files/scripts executed by the web server have been signed and valid so that alteration to script will not run?

Tags: python, django, security, web-applications

Can I create loader or verification that the python files/scripts executed by the web server have been signed and valid so that alteration to script will not run if signature doesn't match?

Is this possible with Django or any other python framework and server?

Comment: How would people modify your server's scripts? If your server allows unauthorized access to change code, you have a bigger problem than just this.

Comment: Let's say sever got hacked and someone added malware into the page. So if we have code sign/verification enabled then it won't run that script.